# What’s the best strategy for embedding multiple tweets (50-60) on a website?

Tags: twitter

I’m embedding around 50+ tweets via ‘react-twitter-widgets’. It takes 10+ seconds to load completely. The tweets are not rendered in sync manner, but rather rendered all at once, and this results in bad UX. What’s the best strategy do adopt here?

Also, while looking at the embedding, I stumbled upon https://cdn.syndication.twimg.com/tweet?id=TWEET_ID which returns data needed for rendering (media crop offsets, video thumbnails) which are not available in the actual api. Is it a good idea to use the https://cdn.syndication.twimg.com for getting renderable information and cache it in the server so embedding is faster?

Comment: The cdn.syndication.* URL is an internal endpoint used by the official Twitter web embeds, and may change in accessibility or behaviour at any time, I would strong recommend against relying on this as it is not a supported part of the Twitter API.

Comment: @AndyPiper I understand. Is there a guide for custom rendering of tweets via response from v2 api ?